# Unreachable code detected no angular

Tags: angular

Observe esse trecho de código;

```
this.notificationService.notify(`cadastro feito com sucesso`)
```

Criei um projeto no Angular, se trata de um sistema ecommerce, toda vez que seleciono um produto ele consegue notificar a mensagemem em tela perfeitamente utilizando esse trecho de código logo acima, porém quando eu utilizo esse trecho de código em um método observable ele dar problema.

Nesse código ele funciona tranquilamente;

```
removeItem(item: CartItem) {
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1)
      this.notificationService.notify(`Você removeu um item ${item.menuItem.name}`);
  }
```

Porém nesse código abaixo não funciona;

```
checkOrder(order: Order): Observable <string> {

  const headers = new Headers()
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  return this.http.post(`${this.url}/orders`, 
           JSON.stringify(order),
            new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }))
            .map(response => response.json())

        this.notificationService.notify(`cadastro feito com sucesso`)  

    }
```

Ele dar essa mensagem de erro =>  `order.service.ts (55,10): Unreachable code detected.`

**O erro que eu tomei é porque tem uma linha de código depois de um return.**

*Para notificar em uma resposta bem sucedida, basta chamar no subscribe do Observable ou usar o operador do. Por exemplo, mas eu não sei modificar meu código para funcionar apesar de saber na teoria como resolver.*

Preciso de ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você mesmo disse ele não faz o notifty pois está após um return.
Para resolver, onde você chama o método `checkOrder`você pode chamar o notify dentro do subscribe.

```
this.service.checkOrder(parametroquevocepassou)
.subscribe(res => {
   this.notificationService.notify(`cadastro feito com sucesso`)  
})
```

Comment: Essa sugestão seria uma boa alternativa se fosse usado na classe de componente, mas pela minha estrutura do meu projeto não tem como eu colocar-lo na classe de componente, será que existiria uma forma do código ficar na classe de serviços, estou tento problema por causa de falta de experiência, solicito um pouco de paciência.

Comment: @wladyband sem problemas, estamos todos aprendendo a todos os momentos. 
Há algum motivo específico para a notificação não ficar no componente? 
Afinal, o resultado você só saberá se deu certo ou não a requisição dando o subscribe no método.

Comment: fica tranquilo, porque sua sugestão me fez abrir a mente para resolver o problema de outra forma, mas pode ter certeza que sua sugestão foi boa, muito obrigado.